# How to pull first character from excel cell from a different tab in spreadsheet

Tags: excel-formula

I want to get a user's middle initial by pulling it from their middle name which is on a different tab in the spreadsheet. I've been pulling info from this other tab by using formulas like:

=IF(LEN(Source!C2)=0, "",Source!I2)

Source is the name of the tab I am pulling the data from. C2 is where I want the initial to appear. I2 is where the middle name is on the Source tab.

This has worked great. I know that I need to use something like LEFT(M2,1) in order to pull the first character from a cell, but I'm not sure where to add it to my existing formula so that I'm only getting the first letter back instead of the whole name. I know the "LEFT" part needs to go somewhere near Source!C5 but I'm not sure where. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF(LEN(Source!C2)=0, "",LEFT(Source!I2,1))
```

Source!I2 always acts as a single reference.